# Who am I? (a riddle without a difference)

Tags: riddle, wordplay

> A lazy insect's friend am I
>   My teeth are what you know me by
>
> Oft mistaken for my cousin
>   Look close - she's fat while I am thin
>
> I know that I'm not worthy of leading
>   Except sometimes in the early morning
>
> Yet my siblings appreciate when
>   I am standing right beside them
>
> If at a cross purpose we should appear
>   Either they or I would disappear
>
> And when I rise alone up above
>   Then shall they all become one, and how!
>
> But don't you try to put me down
>   For consequences untold abound

Comment: "None of your business!"

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You are...

> Zero.

Explanations:

A lazy insect's friend am I/
My teeth are what you know me by

> In [Beetle Bailey](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beetle_Bailey) comics, **bucktoothed** (also lazy) [Private Zero](http://beetlebailey.com/comic_tag/zero/) is lazy Private **Beetle's** barracks mate and good friend.

Oft mistaken for my cousin/
Look close - she's fat while I am thin

> I look like the letter O, but am written slightly skinnier

I know that I'm not worthy of leading/
Except sometimes in the early morning

> Numbers are generally not written with a leading 0 (because a leading 0 is worthless), but in a 24-hour clock, you might report an early-morning time as "0800 hours".

Yet my siblings appreciate when/
I am standing right beside them

> Putting a 0 to the right of other numbers increases their value (i.e. they appreciate).

If at a cross purpose we should appear/
Either they or I would disappear

> Multiplying a number by zero makes it disappear, and adding it to zero makes the zero disappear. Both operations can be represented by crosses.

And when I rise alone up above/
Then shall they all become one, and how!

> Raising something to the power of zero makes it one.

But don't you try to put me down/
For consequences untold abound

> You can't put 0 in the bottom of a fraction because that's dividing by zero (the result of which is undefined or infinite).

Without a difference

> Zero can mean "no difference"

Comment: I suspect that the freind of a lazy insect is a "zero", or someone who can make even a lazy insect look good in comparison (i.e. a foil) - and this is reinforced by the second line (zero has no teeth, thus it's not intimidating, compared to anything)

Comment: "Without a difference" probably refers to the fact that the riddle references all the main arithmetic operations except subtraction. Great riddle and solution!

Comment: That was a quick reply @histocrat!  Good work with the first couplet, @humn!